# Creating session from referrer

Tags: php, mysql, session

**Background:** I have a website, which we'll call AwesomeSite.com; it handles all of my traffic. Additionally, for the purposes of marketing I have a second domain, which we'll call PromoForAwesomeSite.com; it redirects all traffic straight to AwesomeSite. Both sites are built using PHP, MySQL, and Apache.

**Problem**: I want to serve up different content to users based on how they came to my site. Specifically, I want to show promos if the user was redirected from PromoForAwesomeSite.

**Question:** How can I detect that a user came from PromoForAwesomeSite and thus create a different session state for them?

*p.s. I am well aware of the shortcomings of this approach, in that once a session cookie is deleted promo users cannot see the promo content unless they revisit the redirect site (not likely). Unfortunately, this cannot be helped.*

Comment: why $_SERVER[''HTTP_REFERER'] is not applicable to your objective?

Comment: Why not pass a variable to the redirected URL? E.g. On PromoForAwesomeSite.com `header('Location: http://www.awesomesite.com/index.php?promo=1');`. Then on AwesomeSite.com check `if($_GET['promo']){ /* show promos */ }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and see if contains the `PromoForAwesomeSite.com` in the referrer string. For instance something like this:

```
session_start();

if(substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , 'PromoForAwesomeSite.com')){
    $_SESSION['from_promo'] = 1;
}
```

As referrers can be blocked by the browsers, so you might look into the possibility of sending a GET param in the redirect string from the promo site. Not sure how you are redirecting from your promo site but if its PHP you can do something like this , if not you will get the idea what I mean :)

```
HEADER('Location: http://AwesomeSite.com/index.php?from=promo');
```

So instead of (or in additional to) checking the referrer you can also check for this string and save in the session.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the referrer won't be carried on if you do an automatic redirect at the landing time. Thus, If I were you, I would handle it like this:

**1. On *PromoForAwesomeSite.com***

```
header('Location: http://www.awesomesite.com/promo.php');
```

**2. On *AwesomeSite.com***

a. Create a `promo.php` gateway page

b. On the gateway page

```
setcookie('Promo', '1', time()+(5 * (24 * 3600))); // five days promotion cookie - adjust it
header('Location: http://www.awesomesite.com/index.php');
```

c. On the `index.php`

```
if($_COOKIE['Promo']){
    // show promotion
}
```

This way you will solve the issue with the session as well.